# Simple TCP client with control over SYN, ACK, FIN

Tags: networking, tcp, telnet

I am troubleshooting a problem with a telnet server on an embedded device and I need to recreate a specific process where a client closes the socket before the server has completed the initial connection setup/handshake.

Specifically, I need to send a TCP ACK immediately followed by a FIN at a specific point in the communication. I have found some tools that allow me to replay captured packets but I need to actually send my packets in response to the embedded server's packets.

Is there any tool that already has this capability to customize responses or is there a way to use something like Python or C# to create a custom TCP client where I can control the TCP connection at the level of seeing and manipulating the SYN/ACK/FIN packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any tool that already has this capability

Yes, you can create a customized packet with hping3

and also Scapy is a packet manipulation tool for computer network written in Python.
first you need to setup some MiTM solution so all the communications between both ends traverse though your device or script and let you modifiy packet data.

Comment: Scapy is exactly what I was looking for. That's a great find and something I'm adding to my toolbox for good.